# C++ with DevC++, how to access a file in unix?

Tags: c++, unix

in reading and writing a file with C++ on a windows directory we can easily do

```
const string path = "//user/desktop/FILE.txt";
std::ifstream(path.c_str());
```

How about accessing a file on a unix? lets say the directory is /UNIX/FILES/FILES.txt
A unix shared file directory that requires login info to be accessed.

How can I do it in windows C++?

Comment: You want to access a file in the UNIX operating system from Windows (on the same computer)?

Comment: Are you asking about network file access?

Comment: you would do exactly the same thing, set the path to /UNIX/FILES/FILES.txt however note that paths in unix are case sensitive. i.e. `const string path = "/UNIX/FILES/FILE.txt"`;

Comment: also, can you provide more context or what you've tried? e.g. are you working on a unix system? or is it network share or what?

Comment: I'm accessing a network shared files on a unix system

Answer (score 0):

> How about accessing a file on a unix?

My immediate response is "Exactly the same way". But then I realize that I assumed that you would run the program directly on a Unix machine. As long as you stick to standard C++ libraries, you can compile the code and run it on any operating system.

On the other hand, if you want to access a file over a network or the Internet, you have to learn about network programming. This is a large topic that takes up textbooks.